# how to retrieve company info using .net from Netsuite (suitalk)webservice?

Tags: .net, netsuite

Trying to get the data available under `Setup->Company information` like(Company name, address, employer identification number) by accessing `Account` entity with the `AccountID` at my end.

```
RecordRef recordRef = new RecordRef();  
recordRef.externalId = "TSTDRV1531161";  
recordRef.type = RecordType.account;  
recordRef.typeSpecified = true;  
ReadResponse response = _service.get(recordRef);
```

Does not return any results. how can I get this info?

Comment: The information am looking for is available in `RecordType.subsidary`. By performing a Search using `SubsidarySearchbasic` was able to get the required.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
        var sub = new SubsidiarySearchBasic();
        var res = netSuiteService.search(sub);

        if (res.status.isSuccess)
        {
            if (res.totalPages == res.pageIndex)
            { 
                var result = res.recordList.ToList().Any() ? res.recordList.ToList().Cast<Subsidiary>().ToList() : null;
            }
            else
            {
                var resultados = res.recordList.ToList().Cast<Subsidiary>().ToList();

                for (var i = 2; i <= res.totalPages; i++)
                {
                    var resPages = netSuiteService.searchMoreWithId(res.searchId, i);

                    if (resPages.status.isSuccess)
                        resultados.AddRange(res.recordList.ToList().Cast<Subsidiary>().ToList());
                }
            }
        }
        else
            throw new Exception(string.Join(",", res.status.statusDetail.ToList()));
```